# Access Query / Report - Error: This expression is typed incorrectly or it is too complex to be evaluated on calculated field

Tags: sql, ms-access

So after reading 9 posts about the same error on Stack I didn't really find an answer to my problem, hence me posting this question.

So in my Access I have a query that inherits from several other queries. With this query a User can get information with a certain Date range. This data is put in a report where the records are shown and internally (in the report) some calculation is done of the record fields.

The problem is, when A user wants data **until** the date `2016-4-22` the report shows up fine. Though when the User wants data **until** the date `2016-4-30` (from day 23 and on it just gives the same errors) the report tries to load but after a while fails with the error:

```
This expression is typed incorrectly or it is too complex to be evaluated
```

So this made me test a few things which I have list down below:

- First I thought the Query itself or the given `WHERE` clause were corrupted / not good so I put the Report `recordsource` with the WHERE clause in a separate `test query` and executed it. This all worked fine (no errors).
- This made me believe that perhaps a single record was corrupted so I went to the date from which on it gave the error (`2016-4-23`) and checked this record. Nothing weird was found.
- Then I thought it could be some field on the report that was giving the error so I removed several fields and after removing a few `Calculated Sum(total)` fields the error disappeared.
- So I created another query and did the `Sum` in this query as well based on my created test query -  this gave the same error.

After these tests I was pretty sure that perhaps the calculated data was just too much to calculate. I also copied the queries data into `Excel` and did a `SUM` of the field there as well. The outcome was roughly **15 million**. I can hardly imagine that a number of 15 million is too complex to be evaluated...

Besides that, I also tried to create another SUM query on the specific field but with the date based on `2016-4-22` (so the one that initially DID work). But now it also givers the error on this date... So there goes my theory..

Anyone has a clue what is going wrong?

The 'base' query in question is:

```
SELECT qryOHW6Verdicht.*
, CStr([nummer] & "." & [qryOHW6Verdicht].[positie]) AS NummerPos
, [ArbeidTot]+[MateriaalTot]+[UitbesteedTot] AS Kosten
, CDbl([AangenomenprijsPositie])+CDbl([MeerwerkPrijsPositie]) AS OpdrachtSom
, IIf([nacalculatie],[Kosten],IIf(IsNull([kostenverwacht]),(100-[otwinstpercentage])/100*[opdrachtsom],[kostenverwacht])) AS VerwachteKosten
, IIf([nacalculatie],[kosten],IIf([Kosten]<[VerwachteKosten],[Opdrachtsom]-[VerwachteKosten],[Opdrachtsom]-[Kosten])) AS VerwachteWinst
, [Kosten]-[VerkoopTot] AS WaardeOHW
, DatePart("yyyy",[gereeddatum]) AS GereedJaar
, [OtOverhead]*[VerkoopTot]/100 AS Overhead
, qryVCBoekingenVerdicht.KostenVerwacht
FROM qryOHW6Verdicht LEFT JOIN qryVCBoekingenVerdicht 
  ON (qryOHW6Verdicht.[Positie] = qryVCBoekingenVerdicht.[Positie]) 
  AND (qryOHW6Verdicht.[Nummer] = qryVCBoekingenVerdicht.[Offerte])
```

The report opens with the previous query as recordsource and with this WHERE filter:

```
1=1 AND (Gereeddatum is null OR Gereeddatum>=#2016-4-30# ) 
  AND Project IS NULL AND NOT (WaardeOHW=0 AND Kosten=0) AND GarantieOrder=0
```

In the report I got a few Calculated fields and one of them that goes wrong is:

```
=Sum([OpdrachtSom])
```

Comment: Is the whole WHERE filter of the report dynamic, or are some of these constraints static and could go into a WHERE clause of the query? --- How many records does the base query return (roughly)?

Comment: If it works for a certain date range and not for another then it almost certainly is a single record or a small number of records causing the problem. First use process of elimination to find which days work and which do not, then examine your records for missing data. The most common issue is a null value or a value that is converted from string to number somewhere along your process. Run each of the sub-queries manually for the date range that is failing and see what happens.

Comment: You were right. It was a single record that caused the error. Because of the many fields in it I just missed it. It was a NULL value in a field that was used in several query calculations. I was searching for the error in a way to difficult way. Thanks to the comments I narrowed the error down to one single record. Cheers.